# (android) how to close an activity after snackbar ended?

Tags: java, android, snackbar

i want to close activity after snackbar is over.
i have two activties A and B. A activity is open B activity using intent.
at B, when snackbar is over in 3 seconds, B is close automatically using finish().
But how to know that snackbar is over?
as soon as snackbar was launched, B activity close right away because snackbar is over.

Code in B activity.

```
Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(wc, "SAVE", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setDuration(3000);
sb.show();
finish();
```

plz help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a callback in your snackbar like this:

```
sb.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
        if (event == Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT) {
            // finish your activity here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.
may i question? in your code, where should sb.show() be located?
in onShow()? or.. in front of sb.addCallback?

Comment: After adding the callback, show the SnackBar like this:
`Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(wc, "SAVE", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setDuration(3000);
sb.addCallback(){};
sb.show();`

Comment: Is wc your root view in layout file?